# Using FindToolWindow in a 2015 VSIX AsyncPackage during InitializeAsync

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I am trying to migrate a vsix that uses Package to AsyncPackage.

The problem is that originally the Initialize override method in my Package was using

```
ToolWindowPane pane = FindToolWindow(typeof(ToolWindow1), 0, true);
```

to get to the UserControl that is inside the tool window.

However after updating to use AsyncPackage, eg.

```
[PackageRegistration(UseManagedResourcesOnly = true, AllowsBackgroundLoading = true)]
[InstalledProductRegistration("#110", "#112", "1.0", IconResourceID = 400)] // Info on this package for Help/About
[ProvideMenuResource("Menus.ctmenu", 1)]
[ProvideToolWindow(typeof(ToolWindow1))]
[Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ProvideAutoLoad(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.UIContextGuids.SolutionExists, PackageAutoLoadFlags.BackgroundLoad)]
[Guid(ToolWindow1Package.PackageGuidString)]
[ProvideToolWindowVisibility(typeof(ToolWindow1), /*UICONTEXT_SolutionExists*/"f1536ef8-92ec-443c-9ed7-fdadf150da82")]

public sealed class ToolWindow1Package : AsyncPackage


        protected override async System.Threading.Tasks.Task InitializeAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, IProgress<ServiceProgressData> progress)
        {

            //await JoinableTaskFactory.SwitchToMainThreadAsync();
            ToolWindow1Command.Initialize(this, JoinableTaskFactory);

            ToolWindowPane pane = FindToolWindow(typeof(ToolWindow1), 0, true);
             await base.InitializeAsync(cancellationToken, progress);
            return;

        }
```

the call to `FindToolWindow` fails, with this in ActivityLog.xml

```
Construction of frame content failed.&#x000D;&#x000A;Frame identifier: ST:0:0:{deb760b0-be7a-4e88-9ef3-c09cfa7c16da}&#x000D;&#x000A;
Frame caption: ToolWindow1&#x000D;&#x000A;Exception details:&#x000D;&#x000A;System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsShell5.LoadPackageWithContext(Guid&amp; packageGuid, Int32 reason, Guid&amp; context)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.GetPackage()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.ConstructContent()
```

If I uncomment the line `await JoinableTaskFactory.SwitchToMainThreadAsync();` in the InitializeAsync method then VS deadlocks on `FindToolWindow`.

So, how can I access the toolwindow during InitializeAsync?

If I can't, how would I do it at the earliest after intialization?

Comment: Maybe this issue occurs with the difference between two methods: [Package.FindToolWindow(Type, Int32, Boolean)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.package.findtoolwindow?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) Method and [AsyncPackage.FindToolWindowAsync(Type, Int32, Boolean, CancellationToken)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.asyncpackage.findtoolwindowasync?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) Method

Comment: Same problem, `FindToolWindowAsync` deadlocks the same. Did you figure out a solution?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe yes in the end I was able to postpone the call to FindToolWindow to a later occurring event, and it was fine at that point.  I can't be more detailed as the solution was specific to my project.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Did you end up using FindToolWindow or FindToolWindowAsync?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe I used FindToolWindow with a call to `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ThreadHelper.ThrowIfNotOnUIThread();` before it.

Comment: Your comments helped me fix my package, appreciated! You should post an answer, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure. But since you want to migrate the Package to AsyncPackage, I think a FindToolWindowAsync from AsyncPackage could be more suitable.

[Package.FindToolWindow(Type, Int32, Boolean) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.package.findtoolwindow?view=visualstudiosdk-2017)

[AsyncPackage.FindToolWindowAsync(Type, Int32, Boolean, CancellationToken) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.asyncpackage.findtoolwindowasync?view=visualstudiosdk-2017)

Comment: I have the same problem, and `FindToolWindowAsync` deadlocks just the same.

Comment: Sadly it's not in the VS 2015 SDK